# State changes while onRestoreInstanceState() has been override

Tags: android

As far as I understand `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` method are intended to store dynamic data before Activity's state is about to go `onPause()`. I made a simple `Activity` with a button which changes its text after clicking on it. I did override both these methods with nothing in their body:

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

I'm hidding and restoring the activity by means of moving to home screen and back to app. And when activity is restored the button's text isn't default, as I expected, but it is as it was before passing the activity to `onPause()`. How does it work if my `onRestoreInstanceState()` method is empty.

What is more odd - I tried to debug to see when these two methods are being invoked and noticed the `onRestoreInstanceState()` wasn't even called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> intended to store dynamic data before Activity's state is about to go onPause().

Not quite. As the documentation for `onSaveInstanceState()` states:

"If called, this method will occur before onStop(). There are no guarantees about whether it will occur before or after onPause()."

> I'm hidding and restoring the activity by means of moving to home screen and back to app.

That may or may not trigger `onSaveInstanceState()`. It is unlikely to trigger `onRestoreInstanceState()`. A better way to test these methods is to change screen orientation.

> And when activity is restored the button's text isn't default, as I expected, but it is as it was before passing the activity to onPause().

Users cannot type into buttons, so the default implementation of `onSaveInstanceState()` ignores them.

Comment: By changing device's orientation different situations is happening because onCreate() would be invoked where I need to use received Bundle for data restoration. What I want is to find our the way those two methods are working. And yes, users can't input in buttons, I'm changing its default text just to check the save/restore methods.

Comment: @AndroidNoob: `onCreate()` is *always* called if `onRestoreInstanceState()` is to be called. Hence, change the screen orientation. "I'm changing its default text just to check the save/restore methods" -- then you will need to save their "state" yourself in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore it in `onRestoreInstanceState()`.